# Angular JS - Issue with injector creation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular version 1.3.9 and when I try to create injector by below code I'm getting error - Failed to instantiate module pAll due to:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
```

code :-

```
var app = angular.module('pAll', []);
console.log(angular.injector(['pAll','ng']));
```

Just like to know

1. whether to include module name in above injector creation - Correct me if I am worng
2. If we can't specify module name in injector then how can we get the injector created by the module

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Probably you are getting error because of something else. here is a working example (prints with `console.log`)

http://plnkr.co/edit/lPZxDVclonGTrpE77KjK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I saw your example and is working. I'm using angular 1.3 does that the problem?